# Create a queue for posts that will have to be reviewed later

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, editing, review

There are many posts that should be placed in a queue to be checked later. An example is [this](https://superuser.com/questions/163658/fatsort-for-windows-7/370458#370458) one, but there are comments like this scattered all over the place:

> [image: screenshot]

Having a queue like this would prevent the posts from getting dismissed from the review queue too quickly (seeing this post in the queue the day that it was posted and dismissing it would be reasonable) and getting lost later.

I suppose the queue would give users a week to edit their answer, and if they don't they would be auto-flagged (or placed in the /review queue, or something similar) to make sure they don't get through the cracks.

I was thinking that there would either be a flag as "needs editing by the OP" or something similar to add something to the queue, but other mechanisms might make more sense.

Thoughts?

Comment: I mostly use my favorites to bookmark questions I want to follow up on later … but this doesn't work well for answers, nor is it visible to other users. I would love such a feature – like a "follow up" review queue or something.

Comment: @slhck, it also does not scale too well (I don't think). Your favorites are visible to everyone though

Comment: I've come across several posts with such comments in the queue already, makes it kind of redundant to review them the same day.

Comment: This is now implemented (mostly) in the first posts by new users review queue.