# Low-Quality review queue

Tags: discussion, support, review, low-quality

For low quality posts (doing the reviews), I am coming across many sort of "half answers" that don't deserve to be answers, and that I should not have to write paragraphs just for the person answering.

But my options are

- Looks good (not many)
- Edit (I'm not spending 20 minutes on one answer for someone else)
- Recommend Deletion (it does answer the question though...)
- Not Sure.

None of these options are good for many answers.

Should I just say "Not Sure" for the ones, while leaving a comment for the poster to expand on it (as I have been doing)?

Comment: That is why I really want http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5191/create-a-queue-for-posts-that-will-have-to-be-reviewed-later

Comment: That sounds like a sensible option to me. I wonder if we could have a 'Questions that need some love' room or thread for such things tho, would help people work towards their badges, and improve site quality as a whole.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Post as an answer

Comment: @JourneymanGeek How about [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4231/superuser-qnlt) I just made? Questions Need Love Too

Comment: If a decent answer already exist, I do tend to have less sympathy for posts that don't cut it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could probably have a room for "Questions that need some love" or a SU Meta question for stuff like this, the same way we handle closed votes, and tags that need to be burninated.

I'm sure there're a few users willing to put in the time for quality edits, or at least comments. I've passed on a few questions i haven't had the energy to edit to others, but institutionalising this sounds like a good idea.

Comment: Room location: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4231/superuser-qnlt