# Review Low Quality Posts - how to manage wrong answers?

Tags: discussion, low-quality

Reviewing low quality posts I often find answers which are very poor quality and (probably) they're wrong (one [example](https://superuser.com/a/1046617/427317)).

I'm really struggling what to do with them

- **Looks OK**: NO, they are not ok.
- **Edit**: they deserve delete and rewrite, edit doesn't solve the problem here (unlike in this other [question](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5302/low-quality-review-queue)).
- **Recommend deletion**: There is no option to flag them as wrong (and also I've learned an answer shouldn't be deleted just because I think it's wrong).

Best option I think would be to downvote them and add a short explanation, but down-voting isn't an option during review (I know I can open the post in a new tab, but it's just time consuming).

How should I manage these questions?

Comment: You vote to close the question, if no reason fits, then use **Other** and provide a valid reason.  Outside of that you click on the question, which brings you to the question, so you can issue a vote.  There is no, "recommend to delete", a question for a very specific reason.

Comment: That's VLQ but downvoting is what I'd do if I wasn't inclined to modhammer em

Comment: @fixer1234 That is an answer share link (note the `/a/`); it's just been deleted. Maybe a 10K'er could edit in the full text of the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the Low Quality Posts reviewing guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180029/295684):

> If the above doesn't apply, choose **Looks OK**. This is the correct choice for answers that are just wrong.

("The above" refers to non-answers and repairable mistakes - deletion and editing, respectively.)

That said, I don't think anyone would blame you for using Recommend Deletion on pointless, blatantly useless answers.

Answer (score 2):

I've run into a few similar challenges these last few days where the review system disagreed with the technically correct choice.

However just as in real life it is not about being right, but about giving the answer which the system expects.

That means opening the broken post in a new tab. Claiming it is OK in the review tab (as not to collect bad answers) and then deleteing it or editing it from the tab you just opened.